# How would I replace a substring in Java without using the replace method?

Tags: java

What I need to do is replace the letter the user wants to replace in a string with X. Here's an example:

replaceLetterWithX("asdfgsdfghfghj","s")

aXdfgXdfghfghj

But I can't use the replace method. I also need to use the substring, length, and equals methods. I'm a bit confused about where to start. Here's what my code looks like now:

```
public static String replaceLetterWithX(String str, String c)
    {
        //This method will return 'str' with all instances of letter 'c' replaced
        //by 'X'

        String result="";
        
        int count = 0;

        //Code here

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). that said, have a look at `StringBuilder` or go old school and create a `byte[]` from the chars of the old string, saving a `X` when you would otherwise put a `s`, then create a String form that.

Comment: @Bohemian I'll edit it so it fits the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a simple for loop using the charAt method. By looping through the strings and comparing each character with the character to be replaced, we can construct the replaced string from scratch. Keep in mind that this is case-sensitive, I suggest you do some research into the Java documentation to learn more about how to do that.

```
public static String replaceLetterWithX(String str, String c)
    {
        //This method will return 'str' with all instances of letter 'c' replaced
        //by 'X'

        String result="";

        //Code here
        //looping through each character in the string 
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            //converting the character at i to string and comparing it with the given letter
            if (Character.toString(str.charAt(i)).equals(c))
            {
                result += "X";
            }
            //if it isn't add the original letter in the string
            else
            {
                result += str.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```